# How to use req.params in express 4 with Mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm stuck in using req.params.id to execute a query with Mongoose.
I use Angular but the problem don't come from here.

I just put the code that concern my server and my route files

routes.js

```
var Product = require('./models/product');     // My Mongoose model
var express        = require('express');

var router = express.Router(); // Do I really need that ?

// function to retrieve ALL employees (working)

function getEmployees(res){
    Employee.find(function(err, employees) {
    if (err)
        return res.send(err)
    res.json(employees);
    });
};

// function to retrieve ONE employee (not working)

function getEmployeeByID(req,res){
    var query  = Employee.where({ _id: req.params.id });
    query.findOne(function (err, employee) {
        if (err)
            return res.send(err)
        res.json(employee);
        });
    };

module.exports = function(app) {

// !!!!!!!!!!!  PROBLEM IS HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
app.get('/employees/:employee_id', function(req, res) {
    getEmployeeByID(res);
});


// ALL IS WORKING HERE
app.get('/employees', function(req, res) {
    getEmployees(res);
});

app.post('/employees', function(req, res) {
    Employee.create({
        firstname : req.body.firstname,
        lastname : req.body.lastname,
        age : req.body.age,
        dept : req.body.dept,
        done : false
    }, function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        getEmployees(res);
    });
});


app.delete('/employees/:employee_id', function(req, res) {
    Employee.remove({
        _id : req.params.employee_id
    }, function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        getEmployees(res);
    });
});


app.use('/', router);
module.exports = router;

}; // end module.exports
```

Then I have my server file

```
// modules =================================================
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var mongoose       = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');


var db = require('./config/db');
mongoose.connect(db.url);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port

var router = express.Router();

// application -------------------------------------------------------------
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});


app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

// routes ==================================================
require('./app/routes')(app); // pass our application into our routes

app.listen(port);   
module.exports = app;
```

The problem is that when I land on the employees page, I have an error : 

GET http://localhost:8080/employees/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)

It's normal since I've not clicked yet an employee so no ID.

BUT, still, even with a click on one employee, it's ID is not retrieved. I mean, the URL is changed with /employees/employee_id but it won't find the ID in the function getEmployeeByID. In Terminal all the console.log give UNDEFINED even after clicking on ONE employee.

I tried many examples and rode the Docs on Express 4 but can't find what's wrong.

Thanks you if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the way you call the `getEmployeeByID` function.
The function signature expects `req` then `res`, but you are sending only `res` to it, which will be wrongly treated as `req` inside the function.

Also, you should refer to the param with the name you gave it, meaning `req.params.employee_id`.

Now you should actually use the `router` instead of `app` which is the more classic way of doing it in Express4.

```
function getEmployeeByID(req, res){
    var query  = Employee.where({ _id: req.params.employee_id }); // <-- Use the correct param name
    query.findOne(function (err, employee) {
        if (err)
            return res.send(err)
        res.json(employee);
        });
    };

module.exports = function(app) {

// User router instead of app
router.get('/employees/:employee_id', function(req, res) {
    getEmployeeByID(req, res); // <-- sending both req and res to the function
});
```

I've never used moongoose (am a mongodb native driver user) so can't comment on that part of the code.

Comment: Yeah, thanks you I understand my error. Now I see my json response in the browser :) But not in the angular view, I must have a little thing to fix. Anyway, thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem.

*userController.js*

```
exports.getUser  = (req, res) => {

const  _id  =  req.params.id        

UserModel.findById(_id).then((user) => {

if (!user) {

return  res.status(404).send()

}         

res.send(user)

}).catch((error) => {

res.status(500).send(error)

})    
}
```

*router.js*

> `router.get('/users/:id', userController.getUser)`